# How to Install PHP Extension Crypto in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apache2, php

I am new to ubuntu. I am trying to install php 7.0 in my ubuntu 14.04

I have installed PHP using below commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get install php7.0
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql
```

I was able to successfully install php and working fine. Now I want install some custom module in it but I am unable to do it.

I was able to do it in centos 7 using below commands.

```
wget https://pecl.php.net/get/crypto-0.3.1.tgz
tar -zxvf crypto-0.3.1.tgz
cd crypto-0.3.1/
phpize
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

And edit PHP ini like below

```
nano /etc/php.ini
```

and add line in php.ini file like this

```
extension=crypto.so
```

I am able to phpize, configure, make and install but even I edit php.ini file located in

```
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```

but its still not showing module when I run php -m

let me know if I am missing something in it.

Thanks

Comment: Are you restarting apache2? Also be sure you don't have multiple PHP versions somehow enabled (such as PHP 5 and 7 with that old of a Ubuntu) You can also verify with a page that has `<?php phpinfo()` which configuration files are being loaded

Comment: `php -m` on the command line calls PHP CLI commands, this is different from the Apache2 plugin.  If you are trusting `php -m` you need to make sure that `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini` is altered, not the Apache2 one.  Apache2 will only show from the `phpinfo()` call on a webpage.

Comment: @ThomasWard what is means of php.ini altered ? How can I do it? Thanks

Comment: @Mira the same way you edited php.ini - except edit `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini` to add the `extension=crypto.so` line.

Comment: @ThomasWard thanks for that info. I will add there. One more questions after I run sudo make install, and when I try ls, I am not able to find crypto.so there, instead I can see crypto.ls etc. it can be issue ? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

From the github page of the package:

> Linux
>
> Before starting with installation of this extensions, the OpenSSL library has to be installed. It is defaultly installed on the most Linux distributions. The minimal version of OpenSSL that is supported is 0.9.8 but it is recommended to have installed version 1.0.1+ to use all features.
>
> Of course PHP has to be installed too. The minimal version that is supported is 5.3 as the extension uses namespaces. Currently PHP also needs to be compiled with OpenSSL extension (--with-openssl). This dependency will be removed in the future.

Comment: Mind detailing how this answers the question?